# Regex to check password validation based on given conditions?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, passwords

What is the regex to make sure that a given string matches the following 
conditions?

1. Minimum length of eight characters.
2. Should be a combination of three of the following:

   ```
       a. Upper case characters 
       b. Lower Case characters 
       c. Numbers 
       d. Special characters `(!@#$%^&*?/)`
   ```

I know a regular expression which could help me to check if the String matches all the points mentions under #2. But I want to know how we can check for combinations?

Regex currently used:

```
^(?=.[a-z])(?=.[A-Z])(?=.\d)(?=.(_|[!@#$%^&*?/])).{8,}$
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Whatever you are looking for, learning or using a good password checker, this might be helpful: https://blogs.dropbox.com/tech/2012/04/zxcvbn-realistic-password-strength-estimation/

Answer (score 3):

You want want to use `.*` instead of `.` in the lookaheads

For example: `(?=.*[a-z])` instead of `(?=.[a-z])`

**Explanation**

The `.` just matches **one** of *any* character, so currently, your lookaheads are only checking that the **second** character matches `[a-z]`, `[A-Z]`, `\d`, or `[_|[!@#$%^&*?/]`.

---

> **But** don't do this because even if you implement it properly, this is a horrible password policy.

These kind of password policies are for people that don't really understand how to create strong passwords. Password crackers don't consider a capital letter or a `$` to be "special" in any sort of way. Enforcing this kind of thing only makes passwords harder to remember for humans. It's much better for you to educate your users on how to create strong passwords.

### The best passwords are long ones. Like 16 characters or more. Longer is even better.

Implementing this is super easy too. No regexp needed!

```
if (password.length < 16) { /* too short! */ }
```

---

### "Through 20 years of effort, we've successfully trained everyone to use passwords that are hard for humans to remember, but easy for computers to guess."

If you're not convinced, maybe this famous comic will help

[image: Password Strength]

(credit: http://xkcd.com/936/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'm using :  ^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*(_|[!@#$%^&*?/])).{8,}$  now. But it still does not meet the criteria #2. How do I check for combinations?

Comment: Please see the edits to my post. I'm morally obligated to steer you away from creating a bad password policy. I won't help with the regexp "solution" anymore than I already have.

Comment: thanks for the wonderful post. But I'll need to get it validated as per the company policy :(

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, just don't match `.` (any character) in regex:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[_!@#$%^&*?/])[\w!@#$%^&*?/]{8,}$
```

`\w` is same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: Thanks. But it does not meet #2. Eg: Sh1dhgj9 is giving me false, where I am expect it to pass as per the given criteria. How do we check for combinations?

Comment: @anubhava, it's irresponsible to help new users shoot themselves in the foot.

Comment: @user1692773: How will `Sh1dhgj9` be allowed since it doesn't have any of the special characters listed in your question.

Comment: If special characters are not mandatory then use this regex `/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[\w!@#$%^&*?/]{8,}$/gm` and [Also see this demo](https://regex101.com/r/fE1iV6/1)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you are using JavaScript which does not support regex conditionals.

There is only 2 ways this can be done in a single regex.
1. Do all the permutations on *X of Y*
2. Use an engine that supports conditionals.

Since 2. is out of the question for JavaScript, you are left with only 1.
which I get confused when it gets past order 3.

This is how it could be done if the engine supports conditionals.
But it doesn't, so ignore this.

For reference, if you could use conditionals, any X of Y is easily done.
Examine the output match positions for the capture groups and notice how
they are out of order.

Example:

```
 #  ^(?:.*?(?:((?(1)(?!))[a-z]+)|((?(2)(?!))[A-Z]+)|((?(3)(?!))[0-9]+)|((?(4)(?!))[_!@#$%^&*?/]+))){3,4}.*$

 ^     
 (?:
      .*? 
      (?:
           (                        # (1)
                (?(1)
                     (?!)
                )
                [a-z]+ 
           )
        |  (                        # (2)
                (?(2)
                     (?!)
                )
                [A-Z]+ 
           )
        |  (                        # (3)
                (?(3)
                     (?!)
                )
                [0-9]+ 
           )
        |  (                        # (4)
                (?(4)
                     (?!)
                )
                [_!@#$%^&*?/]+ 
           )
      )
 ){3,4}
 .* 
 $
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 15 ) 
B,B_+&*%#a0AaaP
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 9 , len 1 ) 
a
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 0 , len 1 ) 
B
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 10 , len 1 ) 
0
 **  Grp 4 -  ( pos 3 , len 1 ) 
_
```